# Why is my criteria inside IF not working?

Tags: javascript, logic

Even though I enter the exact same input as the criteria, the code still doesn't run properly.

[--> Link to the CodePen of this error <--](https://codepen.io/NiinoTM/pen/WNKJoeq?editors=1010)

```
let addOrRem = String(prompt("Do you want to add or remove any content? (add/rem)").trim().toLocaleLowerCase());

    if(addOrRem !== "rem" || addOrRem !== "add") {
            alert("Invalid answer, try again!");
    }
```

If I write the exact same code in a bundled way, the criteria works properly...

[--> Link to the CodePen of this error partially solved <--](https://codepen.io/NiinoTM/pen/XWBqNRR?editors=1010)

```
let addOrRem = String(prompt("Do you want to add or remove any content? (add/rem)").trim().toLocaleLowerCase());

    if(addOrRem !== "rem") {
      if(addOrRem !== "add"){
        alert("Invalid answer, try again!");
      }    
    }
```

I was expecting the first code to give the exact same output as the second one. I tried switching it for function "while" but resulted in the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your condition should actually be an AND, not an OR.

```js
if (addOrRem !== "rem" && addOrRem !== "add")
```

Consider the fact that `addOrRem` can only be equal to one value, so one of `addOrRem !== "rem"` and `addOrRem !== "add"` will always be true (and thus the entire condition will always be `true` with `||`). `addOrRem` cannot be simultaneously equal to both `"rem"` and `"add"`, which is required for your original condition to be `false`.